# Magento remove promotional code in customer transactional emails

Tags: magento

My client does not want his customers to have a copy of the promotional code they used to minimize the chance they would create a new account and use it again. I am viewing the invoice and order receipt transactional emails, and there is only reference to order.getIsNotVirtual() which I assume inserts details about the order. How would I go about locating reference to the promotional code itself?

Comment: The promotionnal code is part of the totals. You'll find it in the totals.phtml. But AFAIK this is the same template used in many place, so do it carefully to remove it from e-mail (create your own template and change this in the layout of emails only)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to edit the layout of email like this :

```
<sales_email_order_items>
     <reference name="order_totals"><action method="setTemplate"><template>sales/mytotals.phtml</template></action></reference>
</sales_email_order_items>
```

Then duplicate sales/totals.phtml to mytotals.phtml and remove the discount code with something like :

```
if ($_code!='discount')
```

This is for the order template, look at the sales.xml layout to find information about other emails