# Sales email with promotional code - insert promotional code title

Tags: php, xml, magento

I have figured out how to remove the promotional code in the sales order emails via what was said here: [Magento remove promotional code in customer transactional emails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15146103/magento-remove-promotional-code-in-customer-transactional-emails)

Now they want the **title** of the promotion to be included in the email (but not the code). How can I go about this? Is there a variable I can add to `mytotals.phtml`?

Comment: It couldn't have been too vague. I'm fairly certain the answer below is going to be correct.

Comment: Magento people should know what I'm talking about.

Comment: LOL perhaps you could fix my -2 rep score. Not cool guys!

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure why this was closed either.  It's a valid question and the asker cited an earlier question.  I knew exactly what she was asking and how to achieve the goal.  Posting code was unnecessary in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the available information, it appears that you want to pull the title of the promotion instead of the code.  In `mytotals.phtml` you could get the information with this:

```
if ($_code=="discount") {
  $code_used = trim(str_replace(array("Discount (",")"),array(""),$this->escapeHtml($_total->getLabel())));
  $coupon = Mage::getModel('salesrule/coupon');
  $coupon->load($code_used, 'code');
  $rule = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')->load($coupon->getRuleId());
  $rule_name = $rule->getName();
}
```

You can echo `$rule_name` where you want the title of the `Shopping Cart Rule` to be displayed.

Comment: Thank you! How do you go about finding all of these functions to use?

Comment: There's a lot of educational materials out there.  Alan Storm's blog is a great place to learn about Magento http://www.alanstorm.com/

Comment: @seanbreeden ++ Good call!  You can almost call Alan Storm "the Magento guy"  ...  Your answer was accepted, and the question was perfectly clear, why did it get closed?